# Ionic 5, Capacitor 2.4.5 Firebase Dynamic Links

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, capacitor, firebase-dynamic-links, ionic5

I'm integrating Firebase Dynamic Links in my Ionic 5 and Capacitor project.
I did the configuration on Firebase console but I would like to know how to test my dynamic links without publishing the app.

Is there a way to simulate what the user will get after the installation through the app/play store?

What I mean is that I want, after a new installation, to open the app and get the dynamic link.

On Android I managed to make the flow working but I would like to double check it if possible.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: To test the firebase dynamic links on Android you need to publish the app in development mode.

For ios these are the steps I follow:
Uninstall the live app (if any)
click on the dynamic link created through firebase
Install the app
open testflight and install the testflight version of the app

Using these steps you will be able to get the info you need from a dynamic url for both ios and android